# Column length is returning zero when I pass the value i in the xpath using for loop in nodejs webdriver

Tags: node.js, selenium, xpath

This is the code to iterate through a dynamic table.

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath(`//*[@id="slide-wrapper"]/div/ui-view/search-activities/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr`)).then(function(rows) {
                        console.log("NoofRowsinthetable" + rows.length);
                        var identifyvalue = "6/16/17 12:41 PM"
                        var datacount = 0;
                        for (var i = 1; i <= rows.length; i++) {
                            driver.findElements(By.xpath(`//*[@id="slide-wrapper"]/div/ui-view/search-activities/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[i]/td`)).then(function (cells) {
                                    console.log("NoofColumnsinthetable" + cells.length);
                                    for (var j = 1; j <= cells.length; j++) {
                                        driver.findElement(By.xpath(`//*[@id="slide-wrapper"]/div/ui-view/search-activities/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[i]/td[j]`)).getText().then(function (cell_text) {
                                            console.log(cell_text);
                                            if (identifyvalue === cell_text) {
                                                datacount = datacount + 1;
                                                console.log("Data count" + datacount);
                                            }
                                        })
```

First Forloop:
Cells.length returns zero even if there are 9 columns.

IF I AM PASSING THE VALUE OF I AS STRING(tr["+i+"]) THEN IT IS RETURNING THE VALUE OF COLUMN.LENGTH OF FIRST ROW ONLY AND IF I DO NOT PASS THE VALUE OF ‘I’ AS STRING THEN IT IS RETURING THE COLUMN.LENGTH AS ZERO.

Second For loop:
IF I AM PASSING THE VALUE OF I AND J AS STRING(tr["+i+"]/td["+j+"]), THEN IT IS RETURNING THE VALUE OF FIRST COLUMN ONLY

Comment: Please avoid using caps lock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with single quote. you are starting the string with single quote and it should be ended with single. try the following,

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath(`//*[@id="slide-wrapper"]/div/ui-view/search-activities/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr`)).then(function(rows) {
                        console.log("NoofRowsinthetable" + rows.length);
                        var identifyvalue = "6/16/17 12:41 PM"
                        var datacount = 0;
                        for (var i = 1; i <= rows.length; i++) {
                            driver.findElements(By.xpath(`//*[@id="slide-wrapper"]/div/ui-view/search-activities/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[`+i+`]/td`)).then(function (cells) {
                                    console.log("NoofColumnsinthetable" + cells.length);
                                    for (var j = 1; j <= cells.length; j++) {
                                        driver.findElement(By.xpath(`//*[@id="slide-wrapper"]/div/ui-view/search-activities/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[`+i+`]/td[`+j+`]`)).getText().then(function (cell_text) {
                                            console.log(cell_text);
                                            if (identifyvalue === cell_text) {
                                                datacount = datacount + 1;
                                                console.log("Data count" + datacount);
                                            }
                                        })
```

Comment: Thank for the help. It is working now. One more thing which I have observed was the value of 'i' in second for loop is getting changed to 2 in the first iteration itself. Can you please me know why it might be happening, because of this it is unable to get the value of the column as required. /tr[2]/td[1].

Comment: This may be due to javascript array index starts with 0 and xpath array index starts with 1. change you counter accordingly.